# Recognizing a generalized function as zero

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, fourier-analysis

Consider the following expression:

```
HeavisideTheta[x]HeavisideTheta[-x]
```

Mathematica will not simplify it further.  But $\Theta(x)\Theta(-x)$ is zero if considered as a generalized function, since you get zero if you integrate it against any test function: $\int dx\ \Theta(x)\Theta(-x) \varphi(x) = 0$ .

I have a long list of similar such expressions, in the variables $x1,x2,y1,y2$, such as:

```
 HeavisideTheta[x1-y1] HeavisideTheta[x2-y2] HeavisideTheta[-x1,-x2,-x1+x2,y1,-y1+y2]
 DiracDelta[x1+x2-y1-y2] HeavisideTheta[-x1,-x2,-x1+x2,x1-y2,-y1+y2]
```

For either of these, one can integrate against any test function $\varphi(x1,x2,y1,y2)$ and get zero.  How can I get Mathematica to recognize such expressions as zero in a timely way?

I tried defining a function:

```
procedure[expr_]:=
```

that would yield zero on such expressions.  One way that works is to FourierTransform in all four variables; however, this takes hours for some of the expressions.

For completeness, let me write out the full versions of the two example terms above, as they appear in my application:

```
-(1/4)a^2 Exp[(2a + i b)(y1-x1)-(1/4)(a + 4 i b)(x2-y2)] HeavisideTheta[x1-y1] HeavisideTheta[x2-y2] HeavisideTheta[-x1,-x2,-x1+x2,y1,-y1+y2]
2 Exp[(3/4)(y2-x1)b] DiracDelta[x1+x2-y1-y2] HeavisideTheta[-x1,-x2,-x1+x2,x1-y2,-y1+y2]
```

The extra prefactors don't make any difference mathematically (either term is still zero as a generalized function), but they may make it more difficult for Mathematica.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you used `FullSimplify` ? I get some simplification.

Comment: Related: [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41864/i-want-change-gamma-function-form-into-beta-function-form/41866#41866)